# Copy formulas from a range to variant array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all the range's contents in the array and then back to the range.

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim r as Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
arr = r.Value2
r.Value2 = arr
```

I found out that statement `arr = r.Value2` doesn't store equations but their values in an array. So after the statement `r.Value2 = arr` does it's job, equations are gone form the worksheet.

How can I store equations in array and then copy them back?

Comment: You may try `arr = r.Formula`.

Comment: @Harun24hr This worked! Thank you. It copies formulas, but if there are no formulas it copies values. Very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `arr = r.Value2` it is storing only values from range to variant array. Again you are transferring those values to cells. To store formula instead of values use-

```
arr = r.Formula
```